# Is there any way to edit products' features massively?

Tags: joomla-3.x, virtuemart

In Joomla 2.5, you have a program called CSV Improved, you can import/export products from virtuemart and also, edit for example the price of 500 products quickly. You don't have to change the price of each product one by one...
So, my answer is if in Joomla 3.2.7, is there any program that supports Virtuemart, for working quickly and easily with a database.
- Change features of many products
- Import / Export products
- Etc...

Any idea?
P.D.: If I do it manually, it will take me many time... Prices of my online shop are changing "constantly"...

Comment: I suppose you could write a database query and import that query into PhpMyAdmin

Comment: You mean, create a code in PHP to update the features I want massively?

Comment: not, not PHP, just a standard SQL query to update the products prices in a specific table with some where clauses. If you could explain in a little more detail what you want to update exactly and based on what specs, maybe we could help a little more

Comment: I want a free extension, in the last case, a paid extension, to import / export virtuemart products. And if I want to make them a change, like prices, do it massively. To upload a file and update the prices. I don't want to waste time changing features of each product one by one... Do you understand what I want? I just want a "CSV Improved" for Joomla 3.2.7

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of [CSV Improved](http://www.csvimproved.com/en/downloads/csvi-free/csvi-free-5-11)? Even though it says it's for Joomla 2.5, it *might* also work with Joomla 3.x. Please try it

Comment: I can't even open it haha http://gyazo.com/f706925a00e5a901ac5a0cdb6269efa3

Comment: Ahh ok this definitely is only for Joomla 2.5. Try searching on the Joomla extensions directory for other extensions that for Joomla 3.x compatible. I would also suggest you update your site to the latest version of Joomla as 3.2 is no longer supported

Comment: Joomla 3.3.6? Is it stable for all components and templates...? Should I do it?

Comment: Yes, it's the latest stable version. You should always use the latest version as security and bugs need fixing

Comment: You could also check with the VM Mass Update folks to see if a Joomla 3 version is imminent or not: http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/vm-mass-update

Comment: Make sure you backup before upgrading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**NoNumber DB replacer**](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/dbreplacer), is a great extension that allows performing changes massively directly in the content of the database.

There is a Free and a Paid version. 
With the **Free** version you can do **search and replace** in specific db tables up to **50 rows** at time.

The **Paid** version supports **Limiting** your searches with **where statements**, using **regular expressions**, and replaces up to **1000 rows** at time.

I would definitely go with the paid version.

### Backup!!!

However you should be very cautious using the extension on a production site, changes you do on your db are irreversible. So you should be conscious about what you are going to replace, although the extension shows what it is going to be replaced on each row, but **stay safe by keeping backups of your db**.